# How can I make sure apps that are moved to the SD card stay there?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, app2sd

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505, Android 5.0.1, not rooted). Have 16GB total internal storage, and a 32GB SD card - the internal storage always seems to fill up quite quickly (not least because of the 7GB used as a base by the system) so I prefer to keep as many apps as possible on the SD card instead of the internal storage.

The problem that I have is that, if I move an app across to the SD card via the application manager, it seems to only stay there only until the next time an update's installed via Google Play. Something about the installation procedure seems to bring the entire app back to the internal storage (by which I mean, the "SD card app" becomes 0B; however, it does appear to leave the "SD card data" intact), which means that I then have to laboriously go through the process of transferring everything back to the card one-by-one -- obviously less than ideal.

Is there any way I can tell the app manager and/or Google Play  to "move to SD card *and keep it there*"?